# Can I have a "Parent has_many GrandChildren through Children" relationship in DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, orm, dbix-class

I'd like to have functionality like this:

```
$parent->get_grandchildren_by_category({category => 'foo'});
```

I can do it easily outside of the parent class with a simple chained join:

```
$schema->resultset('Parent')->search(
    {
        'me.id' => 62,
        'grandchildren.category' => 'foo'
    },
    {
        join => {'children' => 'grandchildren'}
    }
);
```

But inside the parent class I don't have access (and shouldn't) to the schema object. 
Inside the parent class I can access `$self->children` but that returns a resultset of children, and I'd have to iterate over them to get each one's `grandchildren`.

Is there any way I can define this ActiveRecord style?

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :children
  has_many :grandchildren, :through => :children
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a lot of help from `#dbix-class`.  There may not be a way to explicitly define a `:through` relationship ActiveRecord-style, but there is a way to grab children further down the result chain.

Using the `ResultSet`'s [search_related](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#search_related) method, you can reach through a relationship and use the child's accessors. For example, in my Parent class:

```
sub get_grandchildren_by_category{
    my ($self, $category) = @_;
    my @gchildren = $self->children->search_related('grandchildren'
        {
             'grandchildren.category' => $category
        }
    );

    return \@gchildren;
}
```

Since `search_related` returns a resultset, I guess you could chain those `search_related` calls as far as you want.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but the '_rs' usually represents a resultset.  @gchild_rs is actually a collection of row objects.  To avoid confusion, either call it in scalar context or use search_related_rs instead of search_related.